# How to show the label in the address templates in billing and shipping address in Woocommerce emails and invoice pdf

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The Woocommerce shows the "Billing Address" & "Shipping Address" in email and invoice pdf template as follows:

first_name last_name
company
address_1
address_2
city - postcode
state

I want to display it as follows:

Name: first_name last_name
Company Name: company
Address: address_1
address_2
city - postcode
state

Please tell me, how to do it.

Thanks in advance.